# Find same object in two arraylist

Tags: java

List A={2,3,3}
List B={2,3,5}

I want to get only {2,3} to do the gcd

I tried to use retainall()
but result is {2,3,3}

```
public static int gcd(ArrayList<Integer> A,ArrayList<Integer> B)
{ //A={2,3,3},B={2,3,5}
    A.retainAll(B);
    System.out.println(A);
}
```

Comment: You haven't specified the task clearly enough, that multiple occurrences in both lists are essential, e.g. from `{2,3,3,5}` and `{3,3,7}` you expect `{3,3}`. So, you're getting answers that are correct, but won't help you.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to make use of `Set`, e.g. `HashSet`.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashSet.html

In a set, there are no duplicate values.

`Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(A.retainAll(B));`

Also, method params use lowerCase naming.

Comment: For the greatest common divisor (mentioned as a side-note by the OP), multiple occurrences are essential. So, the `Set` approach won't work.

Comment: Thx, for pointing out, I am aware of this. Out of the question (well there is not even a clear one), I only got that the author needed a distinct result out of 2 Array lists.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `contains(Object o)` method. Returns `true` if this list contains the specified element.
[ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)